# Get value of final field of a static class using reflection

Tags: java

I have following class structure:

```
       private static class MyStaticClass {  
          public final String name;  
          public final String photoUri; 
          private MyStaticClass(String pName, String pPhotoUri) {
               this.name = pName;
               this.photoUri = pPhotoUri;
          }

          public static MyStaticClass getNewMyStaticClass(String pName) {
              return new MyStaticClass(pName, null);
          }
       }
```

Now when I want to read the value of "name" and "photoUri" fields, it gives me "Object is not an instance of class". Following is the code:

```
void printValues() {
    try {
        Class cls = Class.forName("my.pkg.name.TestClass$MyStaticClass");
        for(Field field: cls.getDeclaredFields()) {
            System.out.println("Field name: " + field.getName());
            System.out.println("Field value: " + field.get(cls));
        }
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I also tried to pass "null" at field.get(null) to read the value but it gives null pointer exception.

Please help me, how can I read the value of the field "name" and "photoUri"?

Comment: Please add the code of the outer class `TestClass` for clarity sake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A static nested class is an actual class except that its not top-level. Since you are trying to look at member variables of this class, you actually need an instantiated object of that class to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Your fields are not static, you should specify an instance when calling field.get().

Calling it like this does work:

```
field.get(new MyStaticClass("name", "photoUri"))
```

Comment: He will most likely need to also call `field.setAccessible(true)`

Comment: Don't think so, fields are declared public.

Answer (score 0):

Expression `field.get(cls)` will actually attempt to extract `field`'s value from the `cls`, but `field` belongs `MyStaticClass`, not `Class` (since you are iterating through all fields declared in `MyStaticClass`). This expression will throw an `IllegalArgumentException`.

Use `field.get(o)`, where `o` is an instance of `MyStaticClass` or a subclass thereof.